# Socialfeed not showing notifications from certain sites

Tags: 2013, social, newsfeed, following

We are having a problem with SharePoint 2013 in multiple environments.

A user choose to follow a site (say a team site or a user blog) by clicking the "Follow" button in the top right. The users gets a confirmation "You are now following this site".

But, nothing from the site feed (team sites) or new blog posts are shown in the users feed.

This only happens on some sites; not all blogs, not all team sites. It also does not necessarily impact all users.

We have tried the suggested "Stop follow --> Follow" workaround with varied luck. Sometimes it worked for a while after doing this, only to stop working later on again.

Any idea what the problem can be, or what more to investigate? Are we the only one's experiencing this?